# Which one should be investigated first? dynamic stability or magnetic stability?

Tags: vasp, magnetism, phonons

I would like to investigate the stability of $\ce{VI_3}$ monolayer, but I am confused about whether I start directly by performing Phonon spectrum calculation, or I should first investigate the magnetic stability (I mean is it FM or AFM?). Then, I perform phonons calculations.

Comment: I will go with magnetic first as phonon changes with magnetic configuration.

Comment: Thanks, @pranavkumar I have found that this is the right answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have found that the **stable magnetic phase should be investigated first** before considering dynamic stability (Phonons). Because **phonons are dependant on the magnetic phase** of the system especially if it is magnetic. Also, spin-polarized tags should be included in calculation inputs, like in VASP: `ISPIN=2` and `MAGMOM` tags should be included.